# Two events fired with RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya, disposable

Hi I'm learning some RxSwift, I don't understand why makeLoginRequest is called two times...when login is correct i push to an other controller, but the observable still notifies an other event so it push two times the next controller..

In the viewModel the code is this:

```
let userName : Driver<String>
let password : Driver<String>

var credentials : Driver<(String, String)> {
    return Driver.combineLatest(userName, password) { usr, pwd in
        return (usr, pwd)
    }
}

var credentialValid : Driver<Bool> {
    let usrValid = userName
        .map { $0.rangeOfString("@") != nil }
    let pwdValid = password
    .map { $0.utf8.count > 5 }

    return Driver.combineLatest(usrValid, pwdValid) { usr, pwd in
        return (usr && pwd)
    }
}

func login() -> Observable<Login?>
{
    return credentials.asObservable()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .flatMapLatest { credential -> Observable<Login?> in
            return self.makeLoginRequest(user: credential.0, password: credential.1)
        }
}

func makeLoginRequest(user user: String, password: String) -> Observable<Login?>
{
    return self.provider
        .request(APIProvider.Login(credentials: (user, password)))
        .debug()
        .mapObjectOptional(Login.self)
}
```

and in the controller

```
    loginModel = LoginViewModel(provider: apiProvider! as! RxMoyaProvider<APIProvider>, userName: userTextField.rx_text.asDriver(), password: passwordTextField.rx_text.asDriver())

    loginModel.credentialValid
        .driveNext { [unowned self] valid in
            self.loginButton.enabled = valid
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    loginButton.rx_tap
        .debug()
        .flatMap({ self.loginModel.login() })
        .subscribeNext({ login  in
          // handle here login data
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Anyone can explain what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably lies with code you haven't shown: `userName`, `password`, or `provider`. Also, you included `credentialsValid`, but it's not used. So again, maybe something with that method and how you're using it in your actual code.

On a side note, you shouldn't be using `subscribeNext` nested like that in your view controller. You should be using `flatMap` and subscribing to just the final `Observable`.

See if you can come up with a code example that shows your problem that we can actually run, and then we can help. You'll probably figure out what's wrong on your own by making that example.

Comment: I edited the original answer with credentialsValid that you points out. What is the right way so to don't have a nested subscriveNext? The problem is that the makeLoginRequest method is called two time s and it pushes a view controller, if executed twice it pushes two times and it's absolutely wrong.

Comment: Again, you should be using `flatMap` instead of nested `subscribeNext`s, which will replace the current `Observable`, so you can just subscribe once. Your edit shows how you use `credentialValid`, however that doesn't look to be the issue. I still believe the unknown `userName`, `password`, or `provider` properties might be the issue.  But again, without seeing code, I can't say. And again, you should break this issue down into something simple that you can post here. You will probably figure out what's wrong by doing so, and if not, we can at least run it.

Comment: I find out how I can use flatmap there...but it's not the solution.

Comment: Your question is too dependent on your whole app. You'd likely need to share your project repo to actually get an answer.  However, that's not going to work on StackOverflow. There's just simply not enough information to help you.